# how to get top users in myrrix

Tags: myrrix

similar to `http://myrrix.com/rest-api/#mostpopularitems`, how do i get users with most user-item preferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to flip your model from user,item to item,user and then call the mostpopularitems method.

Comment: isn't there any other option?

Comment: That's right, the model is asymmetric by design really. The assumption is that users and items are different, and that you do different things with them. Users with the most ratings isn't a common thing to query.